# NSWindow update content when show/hide

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I have added `NSWindow` element in my.xib file and inserted some element to it, such as imageView. And then created class of type `NSWindow` named `customNSWindow` and assign these class to the xib element which I have created(NSWindow). Now from another WindowController I need to show/hide the customNSWindow. This is done by putting an outlet to the WindowController.

viewController.h

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *ImageEditWindow;//(custom window)
```

viewController.mm

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {
    if(! [_ImageEditWindow isVisible] ){
        [_ImageEditWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
    }
}
```

But I don't know I how to update image in `ImageEditWindow`, I cannot find way to call a method inside the custom class I created, using `_ImageEditWindow` outlet.

**Edit**

Here is the custom class for NSWindow

CustomIKImageEditor.h

```
@interface CustomIKImageEditor : NSWindow
@property (weak) IBOutlet IKImageView *IKImg;
-(void) updateIKImage: (NSImage*)staticImageToEdit;
@end
```

CustomIKImageEditor.mm

```
-(void) updateIKImage: (NSImage*)staticImageToEdit {

    NSDictionary*           _imageProperties;
    CGImageRef source = [self CGImageCreateWithNSImage: staticImageToEdit];
    _imageProperties = NULL; 
    [_IKImg setImage: source  imageProperties: NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

`@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *ImageEditWindow;//(custom window)`

Should be:

`@property (strong) IBOutlet CustomIKImageEditor *ImageEditWindow;//(custom window)`

Comment: I tried it `[_ImageEditWindow updateIKImage:staticImageToEdit];`  but getting the error message like `No visible @interface for 'NSWindow' declares the selector 'updateIKImage:'`